# MapKit - how to put different images for each location

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mkannotation

Instead of telling what I was trying to do, I decided to show. I was trying to implement the map view that Airbnb did in their iOS app. But I couldn't find the way that they put different prices for each location. Do I need to create the annotation image server-side and push the image to application and show it? Or should I create it in the application side? Since I don't have enough reputation points to put images in here, here is the link of the Airbnb's view.

http://img0.mobile-patterns.com/img/full/1408036269533-2014-07-28%2021.49.01.png

Thank you.

Comment: Point here is you need an unique id to identify annotations. And then images will be set using that id. About image if you want to minimise server traffic load than store it with application, But it will increase application overload too. So it is your choice where to go.

Comment: I do have the unique id of annotations and also the prices that I intend to show from server side. My problem is how to put the custom annotations with prices on them, just like Airbnb did.

Comment: you can use '(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation' to design your custom annotation

Comment: Krishna, I already am using this delegate method. My question is how to implement figures that are created with price tags on them. Exactly like the picture that I put above.